# Laravel PHP get values from specific column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using an Eloquent Model.
Example table:

```
column_1 | column_2 | column_3
---------|----------|---------
data_1   | data_2   | 1
---------|----------|---------
data_4   | data_5   | 1
---------|----------|---------
data_7   | data_8   | 0
```

I would like to get every value from `column_2` where `column_3` is `1`.
So in this case: `data_2` and `data_5`
I tired `where(...)->select('column_2')->get()->toArray()` but it returns the column name too:
`[{"column_2":"data_2"},{"column_2":"data_5"}]`
I need a simple array returned like this:
 `[data_2, data_5]` or `{ "name": ["data_2", "data_5"] }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using pluck method instead of select

```
where(...)->pluck('column2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Model::where('column_3', 1)->pluck('column_2')->toArray();
```

the method `toArray()` will convert the `collection` to array